# Set selected option in dropdown using jQuery not working on IE

Tags: jquery, html

I have two dropdown lists created dynamically and I'm trying to set the default "selected" option using jQuery. It works perfectly in Chrome, but I can't get it to work in IE9.

This what I've tried so far:
JS

```
 $("#dropdown").append($('<option>', {
                value: 'All',
                text: 'All'
            })).prepend($('<option>', {
                value: 'Select Fiscal Year',
                text: 'Select Fiscal Year',
                select: 'selected'
            }));
  $("#dropdownRO").prepend($('<option>', {
                value: 'Select RO',
                text: 'Select RO'
            })).attr("selected", true).append($('<option>', {
                value: 'All',
                text: 'All'
            }));
```

As you can see I tried different ways for each dropdown to see which one worked. I also tried to use `.attr("selected", "selected")`, but the same. Is there anything I'm missing that would make this simple thing work in IE? Thanks!

Comment: You're setting the attribute of `#dropdownRO`, not the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could find to make this work was by adding `.val('Selected RO');` at the end of the chain:

```
 $("#dropdown").append($('<option>', {
 value: 'All',
 text: 'All'}))
 .prepend($('<option>', {
 value: 'Select Fiscal Year',
 text: 'Select Fiscal Year',
 selected: 'selected'}))
 .val('Select Fiscal Year');

 $("#dropdownRO").prepend($('<option>', {
 value: 'Select RO',
 text: 'Select RO'}))
 .prop("selected", true).append($('<option>', {
 value: 'All',
 text: 'All'}))
 .val('Select RO');
```

Now it works, both in Chrome and IE. If anyone has a better solution, please share. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the first block, you're setting the `select` attribute, when it should be `selected`.

```
$("#dropdown").append($('<option>', {
    value: 'All',
    text: 'All'
})).prepend($('<option>', {
    value: 'Select Fiscal Year',
    text: 'Select Fiscal Year',
    selected: 'selected'
}));
```

In the second block, you're applying `.attr()` to `$("#dropdownRO")`, not the `<option>` that you're adding (check the parentheses). It should be:

```
$("#dropdownRO").prepend($('<option>', {
    value: 'Select RO',
    text: 'Select RO'
    }).attr("selected", true)).append($('<option>', {
    value: 'All',
    text: 'All'
}));
```

I suggest you do both of them consistently. I'm just showing the two different ways to write this.

Comment: +1 Good catch. Just curious for my learning, should `selected` be used with `.attr()` or `.prop()`? I know it's an attribute but so is `disabled` and we use `.prop()` with disabled. Not sure about `selected` though. Never really had a need to set a selection like this in js.

Comment: Thanks, but I had both exactly the same way you proposed. I just tried different ways to see which one worked. And no luck so far. This is driving crazy. The only thing that worked was to add these lines: `$("#dropdownRO").val('Select RO');  $("#dropdown").val('Select Fiscal Year');`, which I'm not very happy about.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with the problem?

Comment: Well, the rest of the options are pulled from a SharePoint list using SPServices, I don 't think I would be able to replicate the whole process. Again, it works perfectly in Chrome, but unfortunately 90% of our staff uses IE9. Thanks!

Comment: I tried running your fiddle, but it crashes because `SPServices()` isn't defined. You need to load the libraries.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I really appreciate you help. I'm going to go ahead and add/chain a `.val('Select RO');` for now. It works in IE anyways.